# Navegação entre telas JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Qual a melhor maneira de navegar de uma tela para outra usando JavaFx. Da maneira que estou fazendo toda vez que a primeira tela chama a segunda tela a segunda tela abre com o tamanho da primeira.

Assim é como eu chamo a segunda tela:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("frmPegaXml.fxml"));

SistemaDemonstrativos.SCENE.setRoot(root);
```

Esse é o meu Main:

```
public static Scene SCENE;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("frmLogin.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        SCENE = scene;

        setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_MODENA);
        stage.setResizable(false);

        //scene.getStylesheets().add("css/JMetroLightTheme.css");
        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stage.getIcons().add(new javafx.scene.image.Image("icons/1432842939_chart-icon-tm.png"));

        stage.setTitle("Titulo");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi muito o que você quer. Você quer navegar entre telas, ou apenas criar telas independentes? Dá uma olhada nessa forma:

```
public class Main extends Application{ 
    public static Stage WINDOWS;
    public static Scene SCENE_1, SCENE_2;

    public Parent createContent_1(){
        // Conteúdo I
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setPrefSize(500, 500);

        Button btn_1 = new Button("Cenário_1");
        btn_1.setOnAction(e -> WINDOWS.setScene(SCENE_2));
        root.getChildren().addAll( btn_1);

        return root;
    }

    public Parent createContent_2(){

        // Conteúdo II
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setPrefSize(500, 500);
        Button btn_2 = new Button("Cenário_2");
        btn_2.setOnAction(e -> WINDOWS.setScene(SCENE_1));
        root.getChildren().add(btn_2);

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        WINDOWS = primaryStage;

        SCENE_1 = new Scene(createContent_1());
        SCENE_2 = new Scene(createContent_2());

        WINDOWS.setScene(SCENE_1);

        WINDOWS.setTitle("Teclado Fonêmico");

        WINDOWS.show();
    }  
    public static void main(String [] args){launch(args);}
}
```